# config gmail as a local mail client

Tags: php, smtp, gmail

I have config gmail as a local SMTP mail client. I have use host as smtp.gmail.com, my gmail address as username and its password and 587 as port. But i didnt see any emails send from. I have also uncomment the following lines in php.ini

```
 [mail function] For Win32 only.
 http://php.net/smtp SMTP = localhost
 http://php.net/smtp-port smtp_port =
 587

 ; For Win32 only.
 http://php.net/sendmail-from
 sendmail_from = myemail@gmail.com
```

What am i missing please? I am using windows7 x64. I have notice the php.ini says for windows 32 only? is there a another settings for windows x64?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here you have got full tutorial explaining how to achieve this

http://digiex.net/guides-reviews/guides-tutorials/application-guides/544-configuring-php-under-windows-use-gmail-external-smtp-server-ssl.html

there is also great class that I'd recommend for sending e-mails **PHPMailer**:
[tutorial  here](http://mediakey.dk/~cc/send-email-using-php-phpmailer-and-gmail/)